# Change order of initials/surname in klunamed citation style

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I use Natbib's author-year (in LyX) with the klunamed.bst bibtex style. However, I would like to change the order of surname/initials in the compiled bibliography (see picture) so I get:

`Surname1, A., Surname2, B., Surname3, C., ...`

[This is what I have (upper), and what I want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyTsy.png)

Is there a way to change klunamed.bst to obtain that?

[Link for klunamed.bst.](http://www.metu.edu.tr/~bozsahin/nli/ceng584/link/klunamed.bst)

*Edit*

My Preamble:

`\usepackage[authoryear,round,colon]{natbib}
\bibpunct[; ]{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{;}`

My Document settings:

`Natbib style: Author-year`

Comment: Perhaps you should move to `biblatex` with the `author-year` option as it is easier to customise for the non-specialist: its syntax is LaTeX-like.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've updated my post with some details from my preamble.
I would like to stick to `klunamed` as it satisfies my demands (no URLs, e.g.), but I just have that little annoyance of name order.

Comment: In Western languages (except Hungarian), the order is “(given name) (family name)”. The first author in the bibliography uses the reverse order (with a comma) just to ease lookup.